# For loop in jquery wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have structure HTML :

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="image/image.png" alt="image" />
    <img src="image/image.png" alt="image" />
    <img src="image/image.png" alt="image" />
    <img src="image/image.png" alt="image" />
    <img src="image/image.png" alt="image" />
</div>

<select class="select">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
    <option value="4">Value 4</option>
    <option value="5">Value 5</option>
</select>
```

I want to click an image then select option correspond: Exampble when I click image-1 then option value="1" is selected.
I have try with these line code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var image = $(".image img");
    var option = $(".select option");
    for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        var img = image.eq(i);
        var op = option.eq(i);
        img.click(function () {
            op.addClass('selected');
        });
    }
});
```

But it wrong.Please let me know what I can do to fix it.Thanks.

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: Classic for-loop scoping issue. `op` will always target the last one, for loop in javascript don't create a new scope for each iteration.

Comment: Regarding the title: the for loop is in javascript, not in jquery.

Answer (score 4):

Use data attributes

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="image/image-1.png" alt="image" data-option="1" />
    <img src="image/image-2.png" alt="image" data-option="2" />
    <img src="image/image-3.png" alt="image" data-option="3" />
    <img src="image/image-4.png" alt="image" data-option="4" />
    <img src="image/image-5.png" alt="image" data-option="5" />
</div>
```

Then you can just do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.image img').on('click', function() {
        $('.select').val($(this).data('option'));
    });
});
```

you could also get the number from the source, but data attributes seems simpler

Comment: I think it should be like this: `$('.select').val($(this).attr('data-option'));`

Comment: While i would also use `.attr` instead in this case, there's nothing wrong with using `.data` in this case. (no point in converting the string to an int, just to convert it back to a string)

Comment: jQuery's `data()` is for getting (but not setting) data attributes as well as storing `data()` internally in jQuery, so it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Using a data attribute approach to determine targets is especially useful for cases where there may not be a one to one relationship between trigger elements and targets or for where ordering of triggers/targets in the DOM do not match.  If this is not a consideration for the OP (i.e. the trigger/target ordering in DOM will always match), you could use a more simplified approach of using the index position of the trigger to determine the target, without the need for data attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var image = $(".image img");
    var option = $(".select option");
    for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        var img = image.eq(i);
        var op = option.eq(i);
        (function(op) {
            img.click(function () {
                op.addClass('selected');
            });
        })(op);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**
A simpler alternative:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var image = $(".image img");
    var option = $(".select option");
    for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        var img = image.eq(i);
        var op = option.eq(i);
        img.click({op: op}, function (e) {
            e.data.op.addClass('selected');
        });
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

Although this code should work, there are much simpler ways to make it work. Please consider adeneo's answer and Kevin B's comment

Comment: Thank everybody. I have fixed with Zub's solution

Comment: I'd prefer skipping the for loop entirely and letting jquery do that part. `image.click(function(){ option.eq($(this).index()).prop('selected',true); });`

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the images always matches the value of the select options, i.e. first image matches first option value, second image matches second option and so on, you can simplify this down as follows:

```
$('.image').click(function() {
    var index = $('.image').index(this);
    $target = $('.select option').eq(index);
    $target.prop('selected', true); // selects the option
    $target.addClass('selected'); // adds class to option
}
```

I am not sure if you intended to actually select the option (i.e. set the selected property on the DOM elements) or just add a class to it as shown in your example.  My code does both, so you can remove appropriate lines from it if you don't need to do both.